# Can a goal run in a phase that is different from the default, intended phase provided by the plugin developer?

Tags: java, maven, build, maven-plugin, build-system

I was reading about what a [lifecycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) is in maven, when I stumbled upon this `execution` in a sample plugin:

```
           <execution>
              <id>id.pre-clean</id>
              <phase>pre-clean</phase>
              <goals>
                 <goal>run</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                 <tasks>
                    <echo>pre-clean phase</echo>
                 </tasks>
              </configuration>
           </execution>
```

This shows it is possible to run goals (in this case, the goal is `run`) in certain phases (in this case, `pre-clean`).

In the same page, I read:

> Well, goals can have a default phase binding as discussed further below. If the goal has a default phase binding then it will execute in that phase.

This raises the question, it is possible for the user of the plugin to override the default phase of a goal against the developer of the plugin's intent? For example, making the goal `compile` of `maven-compiler-plugin` execute in the phase `install` instead of the default phase `compile` (while this would never be done, it serves as an example)?

Comment: Yes you can simply define an execution and bind the goal to the appropriate phase you like ...usually you don't define phase in the configuration which means you let the plugin decide in which phase to be executed...if you define the phase yourself you define in which phase it will be executed.

Comment: @khmarbaise is there anything abnormal that would happen if I bound the `compile` goal to a non-`compile` phase?

Comment: In case of the maven-compiler-plugin it would not make sense...